Setting up Flask HTTPS server
I have a task to add certificates to my Flask server. The server is responsive with HTTP requests.
Does anybody have experience how to set up Flask HTTPS server?
I generated private and public keys, with the certbot tool. Information about this tool are here: https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=webproduct&os=snap
In summary, certbot allows you to create private and public keys encoded as .pem files. Which are then used for encrypting and decrypting the traffic which is exchanged between client and server.
I use the waitress library for serving the content to the clients.
This is the line which does this job:
serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=80)

Does anybody know how to transition from here to the state where somebody can access my page with HTTPS protocol? In other words, do HTTPS handshake and exchange the data?
I tried with this line:
serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, url_scheme='https', 
      certfile='path/to/certfile.pem', keyfile='path/to/keyfile.pem')

Which I found this line with perplexity:
https://www.perplexity.ai/search/run-flask-https-server-jPPLZHcERamQ5YBqFlVIBQ

Try configuring Nginx

Run Flask at http://localhost:5000

Create config file in


/etc/nginx/sites-available/yourdomain
server {
    server_name yourdomain.com;
    listen 80;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }    
}


Create symlink sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/yourdomain /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

Install and run Certbot with sudo certbot --nginx -d yourdomain.com command

Reload Nginx sudo systemctl restart nginx.service


